# send_keys doesn't work properly (Twitter automate send message with Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, selenium-chromedriver, chatbot

thank you guys for helping me.

Currently I'm doing a selenium automate send message for Twitter.
This is HTML DOM STRUCTURE:
[image: This is the picture]

So I extract textbox input as:

```
def try_input(driver: WebDriver, msg: str, element: WebElement = None):
    textbox_xpath = "//div[@data-testid='dmComposerTextInput'and @role='textbox']"
    selector = element if element else driver.find_element_by_xpath(textbox_xpath)
    try:
        selector.send_keys(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            selector.send_keys(msg.decode("utf-8"))
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                for m in msg.split('\n'):
                    selector.send_keys(" ")
                    time.sleep(uniform(0.2, 0.6))
                    selector.send_keys(m)
                    action = ActionChains(driver)
                    action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
                return True
            except Exception as e:
                pass
    return False
```

For example I put some text with line break (\n):

```
  Hello this is example text
    This is my first time use this selenium
    Hope you guy helping me.
```

[image: Actaully message text in Twitter]

As you can see here, this is some character missing in `helping me.` and there are no linebreak in textbox.
It's just how it looked in textbox, but when I click to send, this content was fully and exactly. (no missing character and have line breaks)
[image: Exactly message pic]

This is very weird behavior because I have a function to double check content before actaully sending (click send) => I checked the content message in textbox then compare to with I use to send

=> It was not the same (because missing some characters)

=> So my question is: how can I handle and send message exactly with `<div contenteditable='true'>`

Comment: What is the prerequisite steps to get the `//div[@data-testid='dmComposerTextInput'and @role='textbox']` element? It's not appearing on the Twitter home page

Comment: try with send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER): https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys

Comment: @Prophet I was in Twitter messages page when I got this element. So it's already existed.

Comment: @pcalkins, I tried it, but it still didn't break any new line in browsers (for visualization), but it actually had (when clicking send message)

Comment: @DFXNguyễn did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the text with Selenium driver `send_keys` method try doing it with `Actionchains` `send_keys`.
Something like this:

```py
selector = element if element else driver.find_element_by_xpath(textbox_xpath)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(selector)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys(msg)
actions.perform()
```